# AttributeRouting: Why is my POST, but not my PUT routed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET Web API returns 404 for PUT only on some servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099270/asp-net-web-api-returns-404-for-put-only-on-some-servers)

I have created a new ASP.Net MVC4 solution to use the new Web API functionality.  I have a controller inheriting from ApiController and I am using [the AttributeRouting project](http://nuget.org/packages/AttributeRouting) (perhaps best explained [here](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/attribute-based-routing-in-asp-net-web-api/)) to set up my routes.

I have set up the following method for POST:

```
[POST("bank/{id}")]
public void Post(int id, BankRequest bank)
{
    // Create a new Bank here
}
```

When calling this from [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) I can debug this in Visual Studio 2012 and see that everything works as expected.  I can see the id is correct and that the json is automatically serialized correctly into my BankRequest object.  All very nice, I think.  GET also works as expected.

Then I have a similar method for PUT:

```
[PUT("bank/{id}")]
public void Put(int id, BankRequest bank)
{
    // Update a Bank here
}
```

The problem is that I get a HTTP 404 Not Found message when calling this.  All I do is send **exactly** the same url and json in, just changing from POST to PUT.  All I do in Fiddler is change from POST to PUT, so my url and json are preserved.  When I switch back to POST it works fine as well.  I don't know if it is the fancy AttributeRouting that does not work or if something else is incorrect.

Does anyone know why?

Please note that I am setting up an API defined by others, so I have to support PUT.

Comment: What do you use for hosting?asp.net development server (Cassini), IIS Express, IIS?

Comment: I am hosting this in IIS, version 7.5.7600.16385, on a Windows 7 Enterprise version 6.1 SP1.

Comment: Yes, indeed it is a duplicate.  Kevin Ortman's answer solved my problem.  I will vote to close my question.  Thanks, nemesv.