# PUT and DELETE returns 404 for asp.net webapi in Windows 2008 Server IIS 7 and 7.5

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-web-api

I run into **500 - Internal Server Error** when `PUT/DELETE` with windows 2008 server IIS. The response I get is:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>500 - Internal server error.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
Formatting 
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
  <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I check my custom logs of my WebAPI I find that the call has not even hit the service.

My earlier experience was getting **404 - Not Found** for `PUT` and `DELETE` and this behavior was consistent across Win7 and Win 2008 Server. For that [I found this fix:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099270/asp-net-web-api-returns-404-for-put-only-on-some-servers)

I applied the fix and `PUT/DELETE` works on windows 7. But after that when deployed the same service on IIS 7 in win2008 server I do not get 400. But I get **"500 - Internal Server Error"** from IIS or something even before that.

The same code works perfectly on windows 7 (IIS 7.5).

Any clues on resolution of such issues?

**Edited Aug 29, 2012:**

The issue of **500-Internal Server Error** is detected by enabling fault-tracing in IIS7. The fix is this configuration.

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
<handlers>
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
</handlers>
```

Basically we need to remove "WebDAVModule" from modules and also remove "WebDAV" from Handlers. But now I am back to my old issue of **404-Not Found**. Now even after having the below configuration i cannot get PUT/DELETE to work:

```
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

Unusually the same web application works perfectly on hosted separately (not under default web site) on the same system same IIS. So I suspect this is due to some parent website configuration which filters PUT/DELETE requests.

Any ideas on the same?

Comment: Please don't issue corrections as comments.  You can use the **edit** link at the bottom of your question, and just fix what was wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: Looks like there is no solution to this problem

Answer (score 4):

After agonizing over a very similar problem, I came upon this solution: 
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/verbs

Using the Request Filtering settings, I was able to globally allow the PUT and DELETE verbs in IIS, which solved my problem. It ended my nightmare of 404.6 errors. (btw, I did not have webDAV installed and did add the verbs to the ExtensionlessUrlHandler)

Hopefully this info can save someone some time.

Comment: More of Microsoft's *"broken by default"* system.

Answer (score 4):

I make the Neil S` information more exact:

1. Delete WebDAV from "Modules"
2. Delete WebDAV from "Handler Mappings"
3. I delete WebDAV from IIS components to make sure WebDAV not exists and restart Windows
4. Go to "**Handler Mappings**" and find **ExtensionlessUrlHandler** (for 32 and 64 and Integrated), open it and go to "Request Restrictions" to second chapter "Verbs" and put some of the methods you need to the string. I have the next:
   GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT
   I repeat the changes for three "ExtensionlessUrlHandler" states.
5. I do not change Request Filtering settings

So, 404 and 405 error for Put method was disappeared, I receive 200 status.

This solution works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently on my Win Server 2008 R2 / IIS 7.5 and it took me couple of hours just to found out it was caused by **LiveStreamingHandler**. **LiveStreamingHandler** module on the IIS causes the `PUT` and `DELETE` HTTP verb error.

Uninstall the **Media Services 4.1** with **Add and Remove program** and reboot the server fixes this issue. Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on custom error by adding

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

You will see the actual cause of the 500 error when you browse to the API controller, e.g.: http://staging.site.com/api/book.

You will find more clues from the actual exception messages.