# ASP.NET Web API on IIS7 - Not Found 404

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a simple web api project. When I deploy it on IIS 7.5 on Win 7 using Publish feature under VS2010, it works fine. But when I deploy it to IIS 7 on Windows server 2008 (msinfo32 shows version is 6.0.6002 service pack 2), it returns 404.0 Not Found for the same GET request that worked on IIS 7.5

```
Module IIS Web Core 
Notification MapRequestHandler 
Handler StaticFile 
Error Code 0x80070002
```

I have googled and done all suggestions that I can but none of them worked form me.

Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make sure you are using the correct url/location when making the GET request, if your making the GET request off of your own project then it could change if you deploy to another location.

If you need a more specific answer please give some more details and code.

Answer (score 1):

I was missing .NET Framework 4.5 on the Web Server running the IIS 7.5
[Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653)

These two answers helped me, but in my case I had to change some publishing settings too

[MVC 4 Web Api IIS7.5 HTTP 404 Page Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703090/mvc-4-web-api-iis7-5-http-404-page-not-found)

[ASP.NET Web API returns 404 for PUT only on some servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099270/asp-net-web-api-returns-404-for-put-only-on-some-servers)

I was using File System publishing method and I had to check the file delete option.
There were files on the web server from previous build/publish that caused the problem in my case.

[image]

Lastly, I was publishing the app on a website sub folder. 
The url was something like www.myApp.com/spa/  so I had to change the path to the WebAPI in the js configuration to be

www.myApp.com/spa/api/webApiController instead of

www.myApp.com/api/webApiController

Comment: what "js configuration" are you talking about here?

Comment: I was using the MVC Hot Towel Single Page Application template. There is a javascript configuration file for the client side routing settings.